# How can I add an Object to a NSOrderedSet at the last position?

Tags: ios, swift, nsorderedset

How the Title says - I want to be sure that the object is on the last position but I cant find any functions for `NSOrderedSet`. Is it possible to set it simply at `data[data.count]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`NSOrderedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOrderedSet) is immutable. You'll need [`NSMutableOrderedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSMutableOrderedSet_Class/index.html), in particular, you'll want to use [`addObject(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSMutableOrderedSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableOrderedSet/addObject:), such as:

```
data.addObject(myData)
```

`NSOrderedSet` and `NSMutableOrderedSet` are both a part of the Foundation framework, and do not conform to the [CollectionType](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/index.html) protocol, so you cannot use the `[]` operator like in your question.

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to use [NSMutableOrderedSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSMutableOrderedSet_Class/index.html).

In that case, you can just use:

- **Swift:** `func addObject(_ object: AnyObject)`
- **Objective-C:** `- (void)addObject:(ObjectType)object`

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableOrderedSet *mutableData=[data mutableCopy];

[mutableData addObject:theObjectToAdd];

data=mutableData;